# Uncaught TypeError: getState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on an e-commerce shopping cart app. I am not able to use getState() method to access the store.

This is my code from actions/cartActions.js file that is giving me the error:

```js
export const removeFromCart = (product) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const cartItems = getState()
    .cart.cartItems.slice()
    .filter((x) => x._id !== product._id);
  dispatch({ type: REMOVE_FROM_CART, payload: { cartItems } });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

From OP's comment I guess OP want to achieve something like this:

```
function Cart(props) {
  const { cartItems, removeFromCart } = props
  return (<div>
    <h1>Cart</h1>
    {cartItems.map(product => 
      <div key={product._id}>
        <div>{product.name}</div>
        {/* how you'd invoke removeFromCart  */} 
        <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(product)}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>)
}
```

And you want to achieve this through `react-redux`'s `connect()`. It's feasible, but not in the way you currently write your code.

Let's revisit [the doc](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-parameters) first:

> #### `connect()` Parameters​
>
> `connect` accepts four different parameters, all optional. By convention, they are called:
>
> 1. `mapStateToProps?: (state, ownProps?) => Object`
> 2. `mapDispatchToProps?: Object | (dispatch, ownProps?) => Object`
> 3. `mergeProps?: (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => Object`
> 4. `options?: Object`

We need `state` and `dispatch` in one place in order to create `removeFromCart`. Reality is, in `mapStateToProps` we have access to `state`, in `mapDispatchToProps` we have access to `dispatch`, the only place we can access both is within the 3rd param, `mergeProps` function.

> `mergeProps` should be specified with maximum of three parameters. They are the result of `mapStateToProps()`, `mapDispatchToProps()`, and the wrapper component's props, respectively.

This brings us to the solution:

```
export default connect(
  state => ({ state }), // simply pass down `state` object
  dispatch => ({ dispatch }), // simply pass down `dispatch` function
  // here we do the real job:
  ({ state }, { dispatch }) => {
    const removeFromCart = (product) => {
      const cartItems = state.cart.cartItems.slice()
        .filter((x) => x._id !== product._id);
      dispatch({ type: REMOVE_FROM_CART, payload: { cartItems } });
      localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
    };

    return {
      cartItems: state.cart.cartItems,
      removeFromCart,
    }
  }
)(Cart)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Then you need to show us how you invoke the `removeFromCart` function. You usage could be wrong.

Comment: This is how I'm invoking the function: ``` export default connect((state) => ({
  cartItems: state.cart.cartItems,
}),
removeFromCart
)(Cart) ```

Comment: See my updated answer.